Seeking ArcPy equivalent to Shapely and GeoPandas functions
I have a script that uses some Shapely and GeoPandas functions to make a line shapefile. I filter a Pandas dataframe and then sort by a date/time and a Line Number that groups points together. The Shapely and GeoPandas convert that df into a line shape.
gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gp.points_from_xy(df[X[0]], df[Y[0]]))
gdf.set_crs("EPSG:4326")

gdf = gdf.groupby([Line[0]])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry='geometry')

gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"
gdf.to_file("lines.shp")

It works perfectly but I want to try and be as native as possible with ArcPy functions because of IT lockdowns.  It makes passing around custom toolboxes easier.
Can ArcGIS Pro natively do the same thing as simply?
I have done this back in ArcMap 10  which involved adding all the points to an array, which is added to a LineArray, which is added to a polyLine, row by row. They only had 2 points per line then but I will have potentially thousands of points per line in future work.
for line in lines:
    # Get ID and 2 points to make a line
    nID = long(line[1])
    pnt = arcpy.Point(float(line[2]), float(line[3]))
    lineArray.add(pnt)
    pnt = arcpy.Point(float(line[5]), float(line[6]))
    lineArray.add(pnt)
    # new row
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(lineArray)
    newline = cursor.newRow()
    newline.setValue("linenumber", nID)
    newline.shape = polyline
    cursor.insertRow(newline)
    lineArray.removeAll()


Points to line does it
